# Segmentation fault in C sorting program

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault

I'm developing a function in C that sorts text around a given key.
Let's say you have the following file:

```
this line is first
but this line is second
finally there is this line
```

If you run the program and give it this file as input, it should print:

```
but this line is second
finally there is this line
this line is first
```

because but is alphabetically before finally is before this .

If, however, you pass in a flag to sort a different key, you'll get a different output. For example, if you call fastsort -2 on this file, you should get:

```
this line is first
finally there is this line
but this line is second
```

because line comes before there comes before this . Yes, I am assuming -2 means the second word in each line (like most people would, except computer scientists who always want to start at 0).

Moreover, if the specified key does not exist on a particular line of the input file, I should just use the last word of that line as the key. For example, if the user wants to sort on the 4th word ( -4 ), and the sort encounters a line like this ( **sample line** ), the sort should use the word **line** to sort that line.

My problem comes from this last assumption, I'm using strtok() to extract the word given by the key but I get a segmentation fault if the key is bigger than the number of words in the line. Here is the body of the function;

```
 typedef struct {
     char word[128];
     int index;
 } wordIndex;

char** fastsort(char** text, int word){

char** sortedText;
char* LineAux;
int i;
wordIndex tokenLines[numLines];

for(i=0; i<numLines; i++){
    char* token;
    int j = 0; //counter

    LineAux = (char*) malloc(MAX_LENGTH*sizeof(char)); //MAX_LENGTH = 128
    if (LineAux==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error, malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(LineAux,text[i]);

    token = strtok(LineAux, " \n");
    j++;

    if(token == NULL){ //if blank line
        token=" ";

    } else {

        while(token != NULL){  //segmentation fault
            if(j == word){
                break;
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
            j++;

        }
    }

    strcpy(tokenLines[i].word,token);
    tokenLines[i].index=i;
    free(LineAux); //free Aux string
    printf("token: %s   Line: %d  \n",tokenLines[i].word, tokenLines[i].index);
}

qsort(tokenLines,numLines,sizeof(wordIndex),compareTo); //sorting tokens

sortedText = (char**) malloc(numLines*sizeof(char*));
if (sortedText==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error, malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}


//reordering text
int n; 
for (n=0; n<numLines; n++){
    int index;

    sortedText[n]=(char*) malloc(MAX_LENGHT*sizeof(char));

    if (sortedText[n]==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error, malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    index = tokenLines[n].index;
    strcpy(sortedText[n],text[index]);

}


return sortedText;
```

}

the segmentation fault appears inside the while loop.
Hope you can help, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can `text[i]` ever be longer than 127 characters plus the terminating byte? Because if it can, your `strcpy` is going to overrun `LineAux`'s bounds. Same goes for `text[index]` further down.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka No, I have another function (which extracts the text from the file) that prevents the line from having more than 127 characters (+ terminating) so it will never be longer than that

Comment: What's `wordIndex`? Some sort of struct I take it?

Comment: I wrote an answer which I think explains your crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the code above on my machine. It works, with one caveat; `word` is 1-indexed instead of 0 like you might expect, since `j` is incremented before ever comparing it to anything. So if you enter `0`, as you naturally would if you wanted to sort by the first word, this line is never going to be true:

```
if(j == word){
```

Therefore, your while loop continues until token is `NULL`. Then, after the loop, your `strcpy` crashes, because it tried to deference the null pointer you passed to it:

```
strcpy(tokenLines[i].word,token); // don't NULL me bro!
```

This is the source of your crash. To fix it, I'd make two changes:

1. Get rid of the `j++` before the loop. Let the indexing start at `0`, since that is what is usually done in C and what a user of the function would normally expect.
2. After the loop is over, test `token` to see if it is `NULL`. If it is, gracefully exit the function, maybe returning some kind of error to the user. Crashing if someone enters an invalid word number is bad UI.

Answer (score 0):

Allrigth , I have the solution;

The problem was the order of the instructions inside the while loop.

Here is the working solution:

```
/**
 * Function that sorts text by a given key
 * @param text: array of strings which is going to be sorted
 * @param word: key where the sort starts
 * @return sorted text
 */
char** fastsort(char** text, int word){

    char** sortedText;
    char* LineAux;
    int i;
    wordIndex tokenLines[numLines];

    for(i=0; i<numLines; i++){
        char* token;
        int j = 0; //counter

        LineAux = (char*) malloc(MAX_LENGHT*sizeof(char));
        if (LineAux==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"Error, malloc failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        strcpy(LineAux,text[i]);

        token = strtok(LineAux, " \n");
        j++;

        if(token == NULL){ //if blank line
            token=" ";

        } else {

            while(token != NULL){  //segmentation fault
                strcpy(tokenLines[i].word,token);
                if(j == word){
                    break;
                }

                token = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                j++;

            }
        }

        tokenLines[i].index=i;
        free(LineAux); //free Aux string
    }
```

As you can see, the change is not very efficient but It does work for now, if you have an alternate solution I'll be glad to try it.